# How do I make the last row called "testing" occupy the whole row?

Tags: html

Below are my codes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 10px;
      background: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    }

    th,
    td {
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table style="width:100%">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; ">Reviews</h3>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=3>Games' title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan=2 style="text-align: left; ">picture and profile name</th>
      <th>Rating</th>
      <th>duration</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>8</td>
      <td>36</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>testing</th>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

So how do I make the last row, called "testing" to occupy the whole row instead of just under the row called picture and profile name?

Comment: You used `colspan` in other `th` tags right?

Comment: Not sure if you're kidding. But you've used one in game's title right?  `colspan=3`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<tr>
<th colspan="3">testing</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding it as

```
<th colspan=3>testing</th>
```